# Oracle APEX project

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I am working on a project with Oracle APEX.  There is one thing that I am not able to figure out.

When I create a form and add data to it and run my application it keeps the data in itself so when I try to run it again it still has the data from the last user.

How do I change that and stop the form retaining the data?

Answer (score 3):

When you create a branch on the page you can provide the page numbers which cache you want to be cleared with the "clear cache"  attribute. 
When a page is submitted, make sure it triggers a branche where you set this attribute.

Comment: how do I do that ?? what is a branch ?  can you mention steps?

Answer (score 2):

As @Non Plus Ultra said, you can use the Clear Cache attribute of a branch, or you can add a "reset page" Process to run when the page is submitted. Which method you use depends on what navigation paths you wish the page reset to happen.

Comment: how do I do that ?? what is a branch ?

Answer (score 0):

Option
 1)Clear Cache --Go to page --> edit page(top left first option after clicking)-->in edit page at bottom some where you will see Clear.
2) create Branch when page renders set rest page in it.
i would suggest option one